# PHP parse json_decode array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, json

I have a json_array - `$json_array` which is multi-level the code below "spits it" out correctly but is there a better way of doing it?  What I will end up with is a structured XML document with the array keys as the element names - but they must be in the same format as the json array:

e.g.

```
[1] => stdClass Object ( 
    [content] => stdClass Object ( array ) 
    [general] => stdClass Object ( array ) 
    [costing] => stdClass Object ( array ) 
    [socialbits] => stdClass Object (array ) 
    [options] => stdClass Object ( (array) 
        ( [0] => stdClass Object ( array(array)  ) ) ) )
```

Where 1 is the main array key (actually the id from a database)

```
$json_array = json_encode($data);

foreach(json_decode($json_array) as $k=>$val) {

    foreach($val as $k1=>$v2){

        echo $k1;                
        echo '<br />';            
        foreach($v2 as $k3=>$v3){                
            echo $k3;                
            echo '<br />';                
            if(is_array($v3)){            
                foreach($v3 as $k4=>$v4){            
                    foreach($v4 as $k5=>$v5){                        
                        echo $k5;                            
                        echo '<br />';                                
                        foreach($v5 as $k6=>$v6){                                
                            echo $v6;                                
                            echo '<br />'
                        }           
                    }
                }
            }
            echo $v3;
        }
        echo '<br />';
    }
    echo '<br />';  
}
// } OP included the closing brace.
```

Thoughts and ideas most welcome thanks -

EDIT

I have no objection to edits of code, but for the sake of others please make sure they are accurate.  This is a corrected form of the edit;

```
foreach(json_decode($json_array) as $k=>$val) {

foreach($val as $k1=>$v2){

    echo $k1;                
    echo '<br />';            
    foreach($v2 as $k3=>$v3){                
        echo $k3;                
        echo '<br />';                
        if(is_array($v3)){            
            foreach($v3 as $k4=>$v4){            
                foreach($v4 as $k5=>$v5){                        
                    echo $k5;                            
                    echo '<br />';                                
                        foreach($v5 as $k6=>$v6){                                
                            echo $v6;                                
                            echo '<br />';
                        }           
                }
            }
        } else {
        echo $v3;
        }
    }
    echo '<br />';
}
echo '<br />';  
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what your question is?

Comment: THe "main code" works, BUT is there not a better/cleaner way of writing it?

Comment: JSON is not XML. It's simply a method of representing a data structure using Javascript's code syntax. If you want a JSON string to decode into HTML, you'll have to massage the data yourself.

Comment: @Russel: use a recursive function. Your code is limited to a nesting depth of 6 layers

Comment: @Marc B I agree "use a recursive function. Your code is limited to a nesting depth of 6 layers" but have no idea how to write one ;)

Comment: A recursive function is simply one which ends up calling itself directly (or indirectly). Basically, instead of starting a new loop every time you hit an array, call the main function and pass in the data structure you're in. Return the xml you've built from "lower" levels to the "upper" levels.

Comment: BTW that's an object, not an array.

Comment: Why are you using html line breaks in an XML document?

Comment: @KThompson sorry to say if you actually read the question it says "the code below "spits it" out correctly" then adds "What I will end up with is a structured XML document " OK may be I should have stated "ultimatly" not when this is the code I used to "see" the structure not the XML document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may help you achieve an xml representation of json which is what I assume you require from reading your question:

```
<?php
echo recurseJson2XML($json_array, true);
function recurseJson2XML($json, $root = false)
{
    $element = '';
    foreach($json as $key => $value)
    {
        if(is_numeric($key))
        {
            $key = 'element_' . $key;
        }
        $element .= "<{$key}>";
        if(is_array($value) || is_object($value))
        {
            $element .= recurseJson2XML($value);
        }
        else
        {
            $element .= $value;
        }
        $element .= "</{$key}>";
    }
    if($root)
    {
        $element = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><root>{$element}</root>";
    }
    return $element;
}
?>
```

I tested to make sure it works on a json decoded string and it works... Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: many thanks, no issues just had to quickly "strtolower(str_replace(' ','',$key))" the keys just in case element names are mis-formed (will not be me doing it Thanks and voted up ty.)

Comment: Matt - hit a slight problem / question - the very first numeric key in the foreach loop ie in very top code - [1] => stdClass Object (... I do not want to be tagged as element as it does in your function.  I cannot seem to isolate it any suggestions? The reason is I want to add an attribute to the very first 'element' but not to child 'elements'

Comment: You could do this: echo recurseJson2XML($json_array[1], true);